# groovy syntax vs kotlin syntax vs kotlin-in-groovy

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy

Take this document here for ex: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#groovy

Given I am learning **kotlin for android** and am inside a kotlin android project:

- Why is it that copying the definition on the **kotlin** tab (`val nav_version = "2.5.3"`) doesn't work (build fails on sync), but the definition on the **groovy** tab works (`def nav_version = "2.5.3"`) in my build.gradle file?
- Further, why does the **groovy** tab go on to list a code fragment **specifically for kotlin**:

  > // Kotlin implementation
  >
  > implementation(("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
  > implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

Much confused.

Comment: "why does the groovy tab go on to list a code fragment specifically for kotlin:" - Because if you want to build a Kotlin app, you need Kotlin dependencies, regardless of what programming language you author your build file in.  If you were doing this the other way around and using a Kotlin build file for building a Groovy app, your Kotlin build file would be referencing Groovy dependencies. You can decouple the language you are using to write your build file from the language that the app is using.

Comment: Ah. ok... so the answer is, I'm authoring in kotlin, but (apparently) android studio is building with groovy? OK that makes sense - thank you! I actually thought it was building with gradle, not groovy.

Comment: "I actually thought it was building with gradle, not groovy." - Gradle is a build tool.  When using Gradle you can write your build in either Kotlin or Groovy.  Separate from that decision, the project could be building Groovy code, Kotlin code, neither, or both.